# Why is the boiling point of para hydroxybenzoic acid lower than that of ortho hydroxybenzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

As per the literature at 760mm of mercury, *p*-hydroxy benzoic acid has lower boiling point ($\pu{336^\circ C}$ - [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.132.html)) than *o*-hydroxy benzoic acid ($\pu{372^\circ C}$ - [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.331.html?rid=6bdb2bdd-b3f2-4185-aeee-7d3ea45401df)). What is the reason behind this although for the former we can see intermolecular H-bonding?

Comment: One consideration:  the para compound can have a "bimolecular" hydrogen bond structure like acetic acid.